# Exporting C++ from dll - Domain and collections

Tags: c++, windows, dll, heap-corruption

There are several questions already on stack overflow regarding classes and functions across dll boundries.

Alot of them reference this article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

I want to drill down a bit and ask some more specific questions.

The summary of most of those questions is
1) Exporting templates and the STL across dll boundries is bad in general
2) You cannot allocated on one side of a dll boundry and release in another.
3) Your options are
   a) Export only pure C interfaces
   b) Export abstract classes that are free to use templated and the STL in their internal implementation.

Ok. Well, I've never ever done this in 10 years of coding C++ and it has never nipped me in the butt. I've followed what the article calls "The naive approach." However, I resent being called naive a little bit :), because I've always had 100% of the source in every solution and always built 100% of it with the same compiler and settings, and have been mindful of such.

Recently, I've collected evidence that I have a problem with an object being allocated in on one side of a dll boundry and released in another. So, I may find myself having to change my ways. Perhaps, this is a result from now using third party libraries from Nuget, rather than compiling them from source.

So, I wonder, how can I employ these options when it comes to domain objects (Or in my case, objects with no functionality)

If I can never use std::string, then I assume everything exported has to use c-style strings and the amount of copying MBs of text just increased 500X in my solution, if I want to use std:string internally in my dlls.

Worse, I am pondering the question: How do you then have domain objects that contain a collection?

Consider a class in my "naive dll"

```
class CustomerList
{
public:
    // where this is not trivial
    void AddCustomer(const Customer & customer);
private:
    std::vector<Customer> m_customers;
};
```

and a function or method in my dll

```
SubmitCustomers(const CustomerList & customers);
```

How do I make this safe?
Do I need to go reinvent vector in pure C without allocations?
Do I have to resort to arrays with sizes? yuck? and then do yet more copying to STL containers internally?

Comment: ***How do I make this safe?*** One way is to make sure you release a .dll for each version of Visual Studio you support both in debug and release mode. So then those who use your dll won't have more than 1 CRT involved (provided they use the correct dlls). With that said Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 are binary compatible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017

Comment: There seems to be more to it than simply the version of Visual Studio. All my projects in my solution are Visual Studio 2015. However, one of my tests shows solid evidence that there is a heap issue across dll boundry with a boost::shared_ptr. I've also read that not only compiler version, but CRT, architecture, configuration, and checked iterators make a difference.

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing debug and release. Although I believe Visual Studio may prevent this now.

Comment: Yup, I have checked all those things. I've even gone so far as to compare the command lines from each project for all settings. Still having problems. So, I am considering no longer taking the "naive approach." As part of that consideration, I'd like to gain a full understanding of the work i will have to do on objects that have members which are STL collections, and what I will have to turn them into, and what that will look like.

Comment: One way to avoid the issue is to use PIMPL and get m_customers out of the public interface completely.

Comment: Show code please. Take a shot at an answer for adequate space. Using PIMPL will not change the fact that the Dll expects a collection of customers and that it has to be passed in some manner.

Comment: ***Using PIMPL will not change the fact that the Dll expects a collection of customers and that it has to be passed in some manner.*** You can safely pass a CustomerList to your dll if the container that holds the Customers is hidden from the public interface and CustomerList  is exported by the dll. That way all allocations and deallocations happen in the DLL and don't cross the dll boundry.

Comment: There is no container that holds customers, and even if there was, it needs to expose a collection of some sort. 'Customers' is what needs to be passed from the EXE to the DLL.

Comment: `std::vector<Customer> m_customers;` is your container inside `CustomerList`. if you use PIMPL (with CustomerList) then the problem of crossing a DLL boundry goes away.  Or do you mean you don't want to use a `CustomerList` at all?

Comment: Although it is not the best example since the vectors are returned from the dll: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755215/does-pimpl-fundamentally-solve-c-dll-issue

Comment: An example that doesn't address the issue isn't an example at all. i know what the PIMPL idiom is, however, I do not see how that would solve anything at all.